# ASP.NET Web API : return decimal with leading zeros

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

This is an action method in my controller:

```
public IActionResult GetProgres()
{
    var exampleProgress = new Progress()
    {
        Total = 100,
        Completed = 5
        Progress = 5m
    };

    return Ok(exampleProgress);
}
```

which returns a `Progress` object:

```
public class Progress
{
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int Completed { get; set; }
    public decimal Progress { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting this json output:

```
{
    "total": 0,
    "sent": 0,
    "progress": 5
}
```

How can I force `"progress": 5` to be a decimal with two decimal places: `"progress": 5.00`?

Comment: Seems like this is a UI concern. Why not force your client code to handle that if that is what you want displayed?

Comment: Why would you want to? "5" is a correct representation of the value you send. This seems to be an X/Y problem. What problem are you trying to solve by having it say "5.00" in the JSON?

Comment: Try `Progress = (5m % 1 == 0) ? 5.00m : 5m`

Comment: But `Progress` variable can change